# Use of articles with "statistics" and "facts"

Tags: articles

There is a headline presenting a fact. For example, "There were 18 earthquakes in Italy in 2018." Below the fact there's a source and it's linked. Below there is a paragraph elaborating on the fact. So if I want to say "earthquake statistics show", or "according to earthquake facts", should I use an article?

My confusion arises from the fact that these statistics or facts can also be found in other places. For example, if the title is "Dogs can learn fast", and below there is a linked source supporting the claim, should I write "the dog learning facts reveal" referring to that source, or without an article, since that can be a general fact found in multiple sources. Hope I made myself clear, I am really struggling with articles when it comes to referring to these stats and facts in the paragraphs elaborating on a claim.

Comment: How do you intend to marry say 'the earthquake statistics' with 'source A'? This will govern choice of article (say 'the' or 'nil' [either zero or null]). // '[The] dog[-]learning facts' is a phrase best avoided.

Comment: So the use of article would be appropriate if I was to say "the above earthquake statistics reveal..."  But not "the 2018 earthquaqe stats..." even though they are from that year. Cool, thanks for the answer. As far as "dog learning" is concerned, i realize it's ungrammatical, I don't know why I wrote it that way, it's a bad example, sorry. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No, you use 'the' with both 'the above ...' and quite probably with 'the 2018 ...', as you're referring to _all_ the 2018 results (or you'd probably use 'Earthquake statistics from ...) and thus specifying. // 'The results relating to how dogs learn strongly suggest that ...'.

Comment: Ok... So is it assumed that the "statistics" or "facts" are married to the source, since that's the nature of the article (article based on specific stats), or should I add "above" or perhaps "cited", or something similar to "statistics"? When not to insert the article? Does the reader associate "The hurricane facts show..." as married to the source, or do I have to "marry them" with something other than the article. Or should I have to, in the case of, e.g. "Hurricane facts reveal..." leave it as is, without any article? Idk why I find this so difficult...

Comment: You really need to read existing articles, papers etc. 'Hurricane facts' sounds like something that would be used in a child's guide to weather. To further complicate things, titles often drop articles where in everyday usage they'd be included.

Comment: Ok, this is helpful. Yeah, I'll look into some research papers. Problem is, I am getting these articles from writers that need to insert specific keywords, like e.g. "hurricane facts." So I am kind of trying to find better ways of doing it, without sounding unnatural. I completely agree with you, it does sound funny. Anyway, thanks for the assistance!